# Как реализовать Select с поиском

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-events

Проект C# asp net core. Использую jQuery v3.5.1 и BootStrap 4.

Есть Select:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses"></select>
    </div>
```

Нужно сделать поиск для данного Select, чтобы при его активации можно было не крутить, а начать вводить и отображались подходящие варианты. Реализовать нужно на фронте.

На просторах интернета нашел следующий вариант:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/selectize/dist/css/selectize.default.css">
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/microplugin/src/microplugin.js"></script>
<script src="/sifter/sifter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/selectize/dist/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-selectize').selectize();
});
</script>
```

Скачал с https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js библиотеку, закинул папку "dist" в свой проект и прописал на своей странице:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap4.css">
    <script src="~/lib/selectize/dist/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
```

Далее установил node.js и попытался установить через npm 2 оставшихся плагина:

```
npm install microplugin
npm install sifter
```

Вроде установились, но в проекте я их у себя найти не могу. И следовательно путь к ним у себя на странице прописать тоже не могу:

```
<script src=".../.../microplugin.js"></script>
<script src=".../sifter.min.js"></script>
```

Подскажите реализацию с использованием jQuery без сторонних плагинов, если это возможно.

Если реализация только с использованием стандартных инструментов не возможна,  подскажите как мне правильно установить и прописать библиотеки microplugin.js и  sifter.min.js, чтобы они заработали.

По совету @teran рассмотрел вариант jquery UI autocomplete по данной ссылке (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default).

Первая проблема возникла с импортом зависимостей:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
```

Выдавало следующие ошибки:

> GET http://localhost:18246/resources/demos/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
> 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception:
> availableTags is not defined ReferenceError: availableTags is not
> defined
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:342:25)
> at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307)
> undefined

В проекте у меня jQuery находится и подключается следующим образом:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

если правильно понял, в нем не хватает библиотек.

Потом нашел другой вариант подключения:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Данный вариант вроде прошел без ошибок.

Не понятно как прикрутить autocomplete к Select.
Select заполняется контроллером на сервере:

```
public class FriendsController : Controller
    {
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            int selectedIndexCity = 1;
            ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", selectedIndexCity);
            ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name");
            ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name");
            ViewData["GroupUId"] = new SelectList(_context.Groupu, "IdGroup", "Name");
            ViewData["MicroDistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.Microdistrict, "IdMicroDistrict", "Name");           
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.Street.Where(s => s.CityId==1), "IdStreet", "Name");
            //ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "IdHouse", "Name");
            SelectList houses= new SelectList(_context.House, "IdHouse", "Name");
            ViewBag.GetHouses = houses;
            ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name");
            ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "FamilyName");
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте эту библиотеку: https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices

Comment: jquery UI autocomplete по моему всегда первое в списке, когда речь про инкрементальный поиск заходит.  а у вас какие танцы с бубнами в виде npm и nodejs

Comment: @teran, киньте пожалуйста ссылку на пример с реализацией, я в js не селён

Comment: @teran, создал вопрос с более конкретным описанием 
 именно по jquery UI autocomplete - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281823/Как-реализовать-select-с-инкрементальным-поиском-с-помощью-jquery-ui