# Как реализовать Select с инкрементальным поиском с помощью jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-events, jquery-form

Проект C# asp net core. Использую jQuery v3.5.1 и BootStrap 4.

Есть Select:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses"></select>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать поиск для данного Select, чтобы при его активации можно было не крутить, а начать вводить и отображались подходящие варианты. Реализовать нужно на фронте.

По совету @teran рассмотрел вариант jquery UI autocomplete по данной ссылке (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default).

Первая проблема возникла с импортом зависимостей:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
```

Выдавало следующие ошибки:

> GET http://localhost:18246/resources/demos/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

В проекте у меня jQuery находится и подключается следующим образом:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

если правильно понял, в нем не хватает библиотек.

Нашел другой вариант подключения:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Данный вариант при загрузки страницы прошел без ошибок.

Но при срабатывании обработчика выдало ошибки:

> ```
> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).autocomplete is not a function TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:349:27)
>     at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
>     at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307)
> ```
>
> undefined
> S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
> t @ jquery.min.js:2
> setTimeout (async)
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
> c @ jquery.min.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
> fire @ jquery.min.js:2
> c @ jquery.min.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
> ready @ jquery.min.js:2
> B @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (Create:349)
> at e (VM17 jquery.min.js:2)
> at t (VM17 jquery.min.js:2)

Саму реализацию поиска до конца ещё не доделал, то что сделано:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Получение всех элементов требуемого html объекта  select
            var strHouses = $("#HouseId>option").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join();

            //Преобразуем строку c элементами в массив
            var houses = strHouses.split(',');

            // Поиск в массиве
            $('#HouseId').autocomplete({
                source: houses,
            //    select: function (event, ui) {
            //        $('#HouseId').val(data[ui.item.value]);
            //    }
            })
        });

<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses"></select>
    </div>
```

Суть функции в том, что сперва берем все элементы которые есть в массиве и их указываем в источнике autocomplete.

Как правильно импортировать jquery UI autocomplete в проект, чтобы не было ошибок, которые описал выше?

Как верно реализовать функцию поиска для Select? Примеров в сети для Select не нашел. Не знаю как сделать ввод текста для поиска.

Добавил ссылки на зависимости для select2:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Согласно офдокам написал функцию:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#HouseId').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
                placeholder: "Выберите дом",
                minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
                maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
                language: "ru"
            });
        });
```

При срабатывании обработчика:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:362:27)
    at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Create:362)
    at e (VM18 jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (VM18 jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: нет там проблемы у вас никакой. не надо тащить лишние файлы стилей из демок jquery. удалите эту ссылку на styles.css. Возьмите также свежий jquery 3.х,  а не 1ю версию 10летней давности. И не надо пытаться дважды подключить jquery. Если у вас в проекте он уже есть, то второй раз этого делать не требуется. Подключите файлы autocomplete и все.

Comment: autocomplete подключается к input, а не селекту. Зачем вы делаете join а в следующей строке split ?

Comment: @teran, а если у меня уже установлен и подключен (jQuery v3.5.1), то какие ссылки мне нужно добавить?

Comment: @teran, у меня данные в Select, поэтому я и пытаюсь как-то прикрутить к нему )

Comment: @teran, c  join и split я конечно фигню сморозил )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот страница со ссылками на CDN для jquery ui: https://code.jquery.com/ui/
Вы можете подключить оттуда js-файл  и тему стилей. Либо скачать их к себе и подключать локально.

Далее по тому, вопросу, что вы вроде как пытаетесь решить. У вас есть исходный селект. Вы хотите сделать инкрементальный поиск. Такой поиск происходит, когда вы пишите текст в поле. Очевидно, в селект писать ничего не получится и подключается эта библиотека к текстовому полю ввода.

Есть также библиотеки как https://select2.org/searching которые реализуют поиск на основе селекта.

В вашей текущей ситуации можно идти двумя путями. Если вы можете менять верстку, то собственно `select` вам не нужен. Выгрузите опции селекта в js-массив, и используйте его напрямую.
Если все же очень хочется оставить скрытый селект с опциями, и на основе его выбрать варианты для поиска, то  вот примерный сниппет для этого (включая все необходимые подключаемые файлы). Поле для ввода остается просто полем. Само значение выбранное значение вписывает в скрытый инпут.

```js
$(function(){
   let options = $("#src option").map(function(){
                        return { 
                            value: $(this).val(), 
                            label: $(this).text() 
                          };
                    }).get();
   
   $("#search").autocomplete({
       source: options,
       select: function(event, ui){          
          $("#search-result").val(ui.item.value);
          $(this).val(ui.item.label);
       },
       focus: function(event, ui){
          $(this).val(ui.item.label);
          return false;
       }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>


<select id="src" style="display: none;">
  <option value="1">qwe1</option>
  <option value="2">qwe2</option>
  <option value="3">qwe3</option>
  <option value="4">asd</option>
  <option value="5">asd3</option>
</select>

<input id="search"/>
<input type="hidden" name="search-result" id="search-result"/>
```

Comment: в вашем случае, если уже имеется селект, то наверное лучше смотреть на `select2`. autocomplete имеет смысл использовать, если опций много и селект сам по себе не нужен. Можно делать аякс запрос на сервер за данными, например.

Comment: вот мне select2 больше всего подходит. Для него нужны какие-то  дополнительные библиотеки?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir читайте документацию, там все написано как и что подключать.

Comment: вот добавляю ссылки cdn к себе на страницу: `    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
`, но он мне все равно выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js:2

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir сам jquery надо подключать раньше чем select2

Comment: поменял местами:  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script> Теперь пишет, что нет такой функции - 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument'.  Дополнил вопрос